# Distribution plot with particular x axis

Tags: matlab, plot, stata, distribution

I want to replicate a distribution plot in which the partition of the x-axis is not uniform. (See figure 1, page 46 http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/chang-tai.hsieh/research/MMTFP_Klenow_101108-1.pdf). In this case, the x-axis has the following partition: 1/8, 1/4, 1/2, 1, 2, 4, 8

I'm using both Stata and Matlab but I don't know how to replicate such plot with such x-axis. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Link-dependent questions have limited value here: first, people must open up another document to see what you are talking about; second, if that document disappears, the thread is broken. With no attempt at code and no sample data. this question is a stretch. Please study http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve On the face of it, this is just about a logarithmic scale.

Comment: Yes that'd be possible. One solution which comes to my mind right now: Assume you have two data-vectors `X_nonUniform` and `Y`, you could now do the following: `plot(1:length(Y), Y)`, then you'd get a plot with x-coordinates going from 1 to N (N=number of elements in Y), which is uniform. Afterwards just modify the text of the x-axis, --> have a look at XTickLabel

Answer (score 0):

You can specify what points you want labeled like this:

```
sysuse auto
tw kdensity price, xlabel(1000 2000 7500.25 15000)
```